# Line breaking overflowing div

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div that overflows past it's parent to break the overflowing part into a new line?

What I have at the moment:
https://jsfiddle.net/9f9b4pz0/

```
<html>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="second"></div>

  </div>

</html>
```

css:

```
.first {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the div do break and wrap around inside `.first`? In that case, this is not possible as CSS cannot break the integrity of the HTML objects.

Comment: Would that be possible with javascript or jquery then?

Comment: I didn't get what you need exactly. You need a gap between those two divs?

Comment: Yes, you could probably do it with jQuery: measure the width of `.first` and `.second` and then make a clone of `.second` which has the width of the difference between `.first` and `.second`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9f9b4pz0/1/ ?

Comment: @Zentryn the content inside .second should also break into a new line

Answer (score 0):

I don't know are you meaning to overflow that by using `position: absolute`?

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/5u7q6a1h/1/

Answer (score 0):

By *not* defining fixed widths and heights, but instead *no* width (which corresponds to `width: auto`)  and just a `max-height` instead of `height`.

The usual situation wouldn't be plain colored squares but text, small imagaes etc. which do break into new lines automatically:

https://jsfiddle.net/vxhmu6xj/1/

(You can't break a block which has fixed width - even if you want that, you'd have to use several blocks next to each other which look like one block but can be stacked if there isn't enough width.)